# I want to hide button Objective-C ios?

Tags: ios, button, uibutton

When I define the button on `.h`, it works but when I code the button does not work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nl.png"];

    //create the button and assign the image
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(230,302,32,32);
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
    //UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickActionItem) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)btnClicked
{
    [self.button Sethidden:YES]:
    self.button.hidden=YES;
    _button.hidden=YES;
}
```

But not work

Comment: `[self.button Sethidden:YES]:` Well, inverted upper case, ":" instead of ";". Please, what's your real code? When is "btnClicked` called?

Comment: Your button is a local variable, you can't get it in other methods by using that self.button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@implementation YourView{
    UIButton *button;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nl.png"];

            //create the button and assign the image
            button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame=CGRectMake(230,302,32,32);
            [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
            //UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]       initWithCustomView:button];

            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)btnClicked
{
    [button setHidden:YES]; 
}
```

Your code did not give sufficient information for to see what you intend to do. Can you also provide the header file?

Comment: this way there is not `self.button` property, only `button` instance variable. Also it will be leaking, `button` should be `__weak` reference because it's parent view vill be retaining it.

Comment: @RolandKákonyi `__weak` is not needed to avoid a leak here.  The view controller already has strong ownership since it is in `self.view.subviews`.  Both references are cleared when the view controller is deallocated.  It is customary to use weak references here because the view controller is referencing the object but does not need to really own it.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The problem is that you are creating `UIButton` on `viewDidLoad` Method and you don't keep the instance stored so you cannot access it. Another issue is that you are giving another method to `selector` of the button.

## Solution

Change your target at selector and add the `UIButton` as parameter just like the code below

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And the method `btnClicked` take the instance of the `button` which is passed at button

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button sethidden:YES];
}
```

This should do the trick.